# Javascript replace() if match with previous letter

Tags: javascript, string, replace

```js
<script>
function myFunction() {
  var str = document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML; 
  var res = str.replace("/'Karim'['ganj']/", "gonj");
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = res;
}
</script>
```

```html
<p id="demo">Welcome to Karimganj!</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
```

I want to replace 'ganj' in to 'gonj' only if its have 'Karim' in before. How can i do it? Please Help

Comment: Is it always going to be ganj after Karim? Or do you want to replace anything after Karim?

Comment: Why not replace full string `str.replace(/Karimganj/g, "Karimgonj");`

Comment: it Is always going to be ganj after Karim

Comment: sorry not only for Karim only, Karim is only for demo. Kishorganj, Xganj, Yganj, Zganj etc. I want to replace with ```replace("/'Karim'/'X'/'Y'/'Z'/['ganj']/", "gonj");``` something like this.

Comment: wouldn't replacing ganj work? ignore what's before it: str.replace("ganj", "gonj")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Build regex using `|` to OR the possible prefixes:

```js
const prefixes = ['Karim','Kishor', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']
const replace = 'ganj', replacement = 'gonj'
const re = new RegExp(`(${prefixes.join('|')})${replace}`,'gi')

function myFunction() {
  var str = document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML; 
  var res = str.replace(re, `$1${replacement}`);
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = res;
}
```

```html
<p id="demo">Welcome to Karimganj!
ganji
Kishorganj
Xganj
Yganj
Zganj
ganja
Reganja
KarimGanja
</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
```